# Object in List not deleting on re opening the app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

In my app, I store objects(of `Class1`) on two lists (of type `List<Class1>`).
The first list is used to store all the objects added in the app while the other list filters few of the objects based on a filtering function.
Both the lists are part of a class file(Class2) which I store in the app data using **IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings** .
When I access an object in the app, the object is extracted from the list and on changing any of its property, I click on a 'done' button.

```
done_event
{
remove the object from the first list;
remove it from the second list based on a simple condition (#2); 
change its properties; 
add the new object back to the first list; 
run the filtering function to add the new object to the second list if necessary; 
}
```

Everything works fine when I am using it after installing it on the emulator/device but once I exit the app and open it back again and change a property of an object, the new object is removed and added in the first list, however, it is not removed from the second list (the second list populates with two objects instead of one, I used breakpoints and figured out the object was not getting removed from the second list at step #2).
I am new to using **IsolatedStorage**, so don't know the drawbacks. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you load the objects of the two lists after a restart of the app, but maybe the ApplicationSettings deserializes your objects two times for the two lists so you have two different objects.

Try something like a proxy for the ApplicationSettings like the following example to keep only one valid list of all stored Class1-instances:

```
public List<Class1> Class1List
{
    get
    {
        if(this.class1List == null)
        { 
            if(this.applicationSettings.Contains("class1Key"))
                this.class1List = (List<Class1>)this.applicationSettings["class1Key"];
        }

        return this.class1List;
    }
    set
    {
        this.applicationSettings["class1Key"] = value;
        this.applicationSettings.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was in the way data was loaded into the lists when launching the app (though I still don't know what exactly is wrong). But I fixed it by loading only one list from the ApplicationSettings while the other list populates based on the filtering function. It should affect my performance though, but since I am using short lists so the delay isn't noticeable.